# Objective C, A Question about releasing an object

Tags: objective-c

If I do something like

```
address = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:addressData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Then I know that I need to do like [address release] after I am done with using it.
Because "alloc" increases the reference count of "address" variable so that I need to do

```
 [address release]
```

But I am not sure that I need to release if I do something like

```
 NSData *addressData = [NSData dataWithBytes:buf length:address_len];
```

I don't see any "alloc" in this statement..So do I still need to do [addressData release] after I am done with this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't. You only need to release (or autorelease) an object if the method you got the object from is `alloc`, contains the word `copy`, or if you've `retain`ed the object.

Comment: The use of `new` is discouraged and seldom seen (as it isn't as flexible as `alloc`/`init...`), but you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. In this case you can safely assume that the memory is autoreleased.

All explained in the [Memory Management Ownership Policy](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do the release in your second example. The general rule is that you are responsible for a release if you call alloc, retain, or copy.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no need to release in your second statement. If you `alloc, copy, new`, then you should `release` the objects.

[Objective C Memory Management for Lazy People](http://interfacelab.com/objective-c-memory-management-for-lazy-people/) has very useful info as to when to `release` objects.